# Calling ToDictionary<K, V> and casting from within a generic method <K, V>

Tags: c#, templates, generics, casting

I'm getting responses back from a server with metadata information.  I have a few tables I'm trying to load from json.  The code I want to do this with is as follows:

**Interface:**

```
public interface DALObject
{
    public Object Id();
    public Object Instantiate();
}
```

**Class Example:**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class UnitClass_DAL : DALObject
{
    public string GOOGLEFU_ID { get; set; }
    public int _id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }

    object DALObject.Instantiate()
    {
        return Instantiate();
    }

    object DALObject.Id()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public int Id()
    {
        return _id;
    }

    public UnitClass Instantiate( )
    {
        UnitClass temp = new UnitClass();
        temp.id = _id;
        temp.name = name;
        return temp;
    }
}
```

**Loading Method Inside My RemoteAPIService class:**

```
public void LoadMetadataResource<DALType, K, V>(IDictionary<K, V> list, string resource) where DALType: DALObject
{
    ++activeLoads;
    var parameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
    parameters.Add("table", resource);
    SendAPICall("tables", parameters, (successResponse) =>
        {
            list = JsonMapper.ToObject<List<DALType>>(successResponse).ToDictionary(temp => temp.Id() as K, temp => temp.Instantiate() as V);
            --activeLoads;
        }, (errorResponse) =>
        {
            --activeLoads;
        });
}
```

The issue I am having is that I want to call something like this:

```
//...
LoadMetadataResource<UnitClass_DAL, int, UnitClass>(GameDataHolder.UnitClass, "UnitClass");
//...
```

GameDataHolder.UnitClass is of type: Dictionary<int, UnitClass>

The error comes in trying to cast temp.Id() as K, or temp.Instantiate() as V.  I need to load it into a specific data type for GameDataHolder, not a generic base class type.

Is this possible in C#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Casting value to T in a generic method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856723/casting-value-to-t-in-a-generic-method)

It turns out "as" is not an appropriate way to cast in this instance.  I was able to resolve my issue by simply c-style casting:

```
    public void LoadMetadataResource<DALType, K, V>(IDictionary<K, V> list, string resource) where DALType: DALObject
    {
        ++activeLoads;
        var parameters = new SortedDictionary<string, string>();
        parameters.Add("table", resource);
        SendAPICall("tables", parameters, (successResponse) =>
            {
                list = JsonMapper.ToObject<List<DALType>>(successResponse).ToDictionary(temp => (K)temp.Id(), temp => (V)temp.Instantiate());
                --activeLoads;
            }, (errorResponse) =>
            {
                --activeLoads;
            });
    }
```

I'll follow up if this doesn't work out, but it looks like it will compile.