# Is it possible to return a struct from a generic method, without boxing, with interface constraint?

Tags: c#, generics, struct, interface

```
public struct MyStruct : IComparable
{
    // ...
}

MyStruct FooBar;

void DoThing<T>() where T : IComparable
{
    bar(FooBar);
    T result = foo<T>();
    result.CompareTo(default(T));
    bar(result);
}

T foo<T>() where T : IComparable
{
    if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyStruct))
    {
        // return FooBar;
        return (T)(IComparable)FooBar;
    }
    throw new Exception("Invalid Type Argument");
}

void bar<T>(T value) where T : IComparable
{
    value.CompareTo(default(T));
}
```

I'm trying to write some code that keeps a struct unboxed using interfaces.

In the code above, `bar(FooBar);` and `bar(result)` are valid, but `return FooBar;` is invalid ("Cannot implicitly convert type 'MyStruct' to 'T'"). It requires me to do the manual casts on the following return line in order to compile, but that will (to my understanding) box the MyStruct.

My understanding based on [other questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25508615/are-value-types-boxed-when-passed-as-generic-parameters-with-an-interface-constr) is that the call to `bar(FooBar);` is avoiding boxing, and therefore the call to `value.CompareTo()` would be operating on an unboxed struct. Is there a way to make sure that's true also for the equivalent `result.CompareTo()` call in DoThing()?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov replacing `MyStruct` with `string` in all the code above works exactly the same, as it does and should for anything that implements IComparable. 

My question is basically "Why can MyStruct be implicitly cast to T when it's being passed to a function, but not when it's being returned from a function"

Comment: Not clear what you are actually asking. If you want to know would there be boxing: no there would not, *unless* you pass it to a function that only expects the interface. Calling interface methods directly does not box. If you are asking why you can't return that value, it's because although every `T` is an `IComparable`, it's not necessarily true that `MyStruct` is a `T`, in fact it probably isn't

Comment: @Charlieface my foo function enforces that I only return a MyStruct value if T is MyStruct. It's possible for me to force the issue through casting, so my question is why can't the compiler infer that that's what I want to do without boxing.

Comment: This question is about the same issue and says it's impossible, but unfortunately doesn't explain why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/856723/casting-value-to-t-in-a-generic-method

Comment: The code `if (typeof(T) == typeof(MyStruct))` only works at runtime, it doesn't help the compiler infer anything about the type. The compiler only sees `T`, which it knows is an `IComparable`, and `MyStruct` which is also, it does not know and cannot infer at compile time that `T` is `MyStruct`. So you cannot assign an instance of `MyStruct` to a `T` location without a cast. It doesn't necessarily box, it only boxes if at runtime `T` is actually `IComparable` or another interface, rather than `MyStruct` itself

Comment: "It doesn't necessarily box, it only boxes if at runtime T is actually IComparable or another interface, rather than MyStruct itself" - this is news to me, and would definitely adequately answer my question if true! However, since the only way to get the code to compile is to cast to IComparable and _then_ to T, would it not be the case that it would always end up boxing through that intermediary cast to an interface?

Comment: I was trying to say that if for example you called `Compare` on some value `T` there would be no boxing because at runtime the type is fully inlined. The code you have in `foo` doesn't work because the compiler has no way of verifying *at compile time* that `T` is `MyStruct`. In any case this whole thing is moot, if you're doing `typeof(T) == typeof(something)` in a generic function you're nearly always doing something wrong. You shouldn't *need* to test for `MyStruct`. Otherwise just make a non-generic function